# Will 'at' command be executed after the reboot?

Tags: cron, reboot, at

If I schedule something with 'at` like,

```
$ at noon
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> echo "Will I be created?" > /tmp/at_test
at> <EOT>
job 12 at Fri Jun 30 12:00:00 2017
```

And if I reboot the machine before execution time, will my command be executed?

Unlike regular `cron` which schedules tasks from file, does `at` store this 'info' somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jobs are stored in `/var/spool/cron/atjobs` in Ubuntu for instance.

Jobs are a file with some environment variable set (like `$PATH`, current working directory). The host can be rebooted, if the host is up, jobs will start.

`man at` should tell you more about it.

Note that some Unices have special `cron` entry like `@reboot`.

Comment: Addition in case anybody is interested: at stores Unix epoch of the job scheduled time in the job filename as epoch/60 in hexadecimal format.